# Automate the Boring Stuff: Why don't these Python functions do the same thing?

Tags: python, variables

I'm working through Automate the Boring Stuff, and I noticed he teaches the open module as:

```
baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
baconFile.write('Bacon is not a vegetable.')
baconFile.close()
```

Why do we need the baconFile variable at all? I understand ease of readability/debugging, however, when I try the following code, the text is not input into the .txt file:

```
open('bacon.txt', 'w').write('Bacon is not a vegetable.')
open('bacon.txt', 'w').close()
```

Why? What is the difference between these two?

Edit: People are saying I'm opening it again in the code at the bottom. Is that not what I'm doing in the top code? I thought a variable was just a substitute for whatever code I didn't want to type again.

Comment: Because the second time you open the file, to immediately close it again, you truncate it; that's what w mode does.

Comment: If you call `open` twice, you're opening the file twice, and the second time you don't write anything to it, so it ends up empty.

Comment: But I thought we were opening it again in the top lines of code anyway? (seeing as the baconFile variable means open)

Comment: Also note that that the preferred way of doing file stuff is using a context manager, which is a fancy term for using "with" and taking advantage of built in capabilities so you don't need to remember when to clean up:

```
   with open('bacon.txt','w') as baconFile:
     baconFile.write("Bacon is not a fruit.")
```

Comment: That's not how variables work. Assigning `baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')` doesn't mean that the variable is shorthand for the expression. The statement evaluates the right-hand side and binds the `baconFile` variable to the *file object* returned by `open`.

Comment: What you're thinking of would be a macro (which Python doesn't have).

Answer (score 2):

In your version, you create two file handlers (like `baconFile` in the original example), one for each time you call `open`, and they handle the same file. **`baconFile` is not a file, it is an object to handle files**.

The first one you use to write some text. You never close and it will be destroyed when you program ends.

When you open the second one in `w` mode, it resets the text content, and then you close it.

Comment: Just for my own benefit, is there a way to do what I want without the baconFile variable? Edit: I managed to do it by removing the 'w' in the second 'open'

Comment: @SlayinAlive Not that I can think of, because you cannot chain a `close` to the result of `write`. Also the `with` construct forces you to name the handler. But there is no bad in naming objects.

Comment: It's not a file handle**r** either, but a file [*handle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)), or [file *descriptor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Comment: @SlayinAlive removing `w` in the second open doesn't prevent the file from being opened twice. The first open is still not closed. Each open returns a different file descriptor object

Answer (score 2):

```
step 1. open the file to write.
step 2. write something in the file.
step 3. close the file.
```

you are trying to open a opened file.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought a variable was just a substitute for whatever code I didn't want to type again.

This is a description of [*referential transparency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) in layman's terms.

It works only if you are dealing with *pure functions*, i.e. functions which have no side effects. For example,

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x

a = double(5)
b = a + a
```

is equivalent to

```
b = double(5) + double(5)
```

But in Python, functions are in general not pure. Assignment works by evaluating the right-hand side *once* and binding it to the name on the left-hand side. Using the name only refers to the *value* of the evaluated expression, but does not repeat the *side effects* it could have had.

So if instead,

```
def double(x):
    print('doubling', x)
    return 2 * x
```

then

```
a = double(5)
b = a + a
```

is no longer equivalent to

```
b = double(5) + double(5)
```

`b` is still 20 in both cases, but the first case prints `doubling 5` once, the second case prints it twice.

---

`open('bacon.txt', 'w')` has a *side effect* of opening a file and truncating it, and evaluates to a *value* which is a file handle.

In your example,

```
open('bacon.txt', 'w').write('Bacon is not a vegetable.')
open('bacon.txt', 'w').close()
```

is equivalent to:

```
f = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
f.write('Bacon is not a vegetable.')

g = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
g.close()
```

Which means that the file is opened and truncated once, then something is written to it. Then it is opened and truncated again, losing what you've written before.

Comment: Also, even with referential transparency, there can be efficiency implications (depending on how your language is designed).